# Bounded logistic regression in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, logistic-regression

The [standard logistic regression solver](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/linear_model/logistic.py#L998) in scikit-learn assumes the regression equation:

```
P(X) = 1/ (1 + exp(b0 + b1*X1 + ... + bn*Xn))
```

.. and solves for the `b`'s using various solver routines.

For a specific project, I'd like to bound the regression equation between `0-a` (instead of 0-1) and add a variable `c` to center an independent variable `Xk`, e.g.

```
P(X) = a / (1 + exp((b0 + b1*X1 + .. + bn*Xn) * (Xk  - c)))
```

and solve for `a`, `b`'s and `c`.

Any thoughts/ideas on how to modify `logistic.py` to achieve this? I thought of modifying the [expit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html) function to reflect the changed equation. But how do a let the solvers know to also include the new variables `a` and `c`? Any scripts available that are able to handle my modified logistic regression equation?

Comment: I think, you should use numpy to write the desired equation and then use it, by understanding how logistic regression works, while training a model.

Comment: It would be easier to standardize your data set by subtracting the `c` and to scale the targets by dividing by `a`. I.e. `X[k] -=c` and `Y /= a`.

Comment: If a and c would be known upfront, I could do so. But they are variables that the solver needs to include when trying to fit the data...

Answer (score 0):

It is not totaaly clear what you need but

```
P(X) = a / (1 + exp(b0 + b1*X1 + .. + bn*Xn) * (Xk  - c))
```

that's the same as

```
P(X) = a / (1 + exp(b0 + b1*X1 + .. + bn*Xn + log(Xk)/log(c))
```

so replace `c` by `exp(1/bk)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I was missing a parenthesis (sorry, would love to see LaTeX formulas here :), and the (Xk-c) is actually in the exponent. I’m looking for a mod in the logistic.py to enable solving this slightly modified logistical regression equation